# How to access Docker daemon through tcp-socker?

Tags: docker

I have added

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

to /etc/default/docker to make the Docker API accessible on my host machine (I'm running Docker in Virtualbox on an Ubuntu VM). However, when I try to run any Docker commands now, I just get this error message:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I have tried sudo service docker restart, and restarted the machine, but nothing has worked. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Did you try `$docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 run <image_ID>`? By default, the client may try to access the daemon on the default unix socket.

Comment: Ah, yep that works. Is there a way I can still use the docker commands without -H etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the daemon through the tcp socket the option `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` should be added to the command `docker` (both for the `daemon` and `run`).

To access the daemon with its default unix socket make sure that the Docker daemon is also started with the option `-H=unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

---

Note that using the `tcp` is dangerous if you do not trust the network you are in. Here is the doc from the man page:

```
   -H, --host=[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]: tcp://[host]:[port][path] to bind or unix://[/path/to/socket] to use.
     The socket(s) to bind to in daemon mode specified using one or more
     tcp://host:port/path, unix:///path/to/socket, fd://* or fd://socketfd.
     If the tcp port is not specified, then it will default to either 2375 when
     --tls is off, or 2376 when --tls is on, or --tlsverify is specified.
```

Comment: Thanks. I've only created this vm so I can run Docker containers in a dev environment on my local machine, so tcp isn't an issue. My problem is that now I have added the Docker_Opts value I have to enter docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 to run commands in the terminal.

Comment: Well, that's not really a problem, is it? You can also create an alias. Just add, in your `.bashrc` the line `alias docker='docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375'` and you're done!

Comment: No, I suppose not! I've added in the alias though, so thanks very much!

Comment: If it answers your question, I suggest that you tag my answer as valid, so your question is then tagged as answered (thus people having the problem will know the solution is available here ;) ) Have fun with Docker !