# connect to docker hosted on remote server

Tags: python, docker

How do I connect to remote docker host using python?

```
>>> from docker import Client
>>> cli = Client(base_url='tcp://52.90.216.176:2375')
>>>
>>> cli.containers()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 69, in containers
    res = self._result(self._get(u, params=params), True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 112, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='52.90.216.176', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.21/containers/json?all=0&limit=-1&trunc_cmd=0&size=0 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd87d836750>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

If I log-in to 52.90.216.176 and use the following:

```
>>> cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
```

this works. But how do I connect to docker running on another server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Docker daemon through tcp-socker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488251/how-to-access-docker-daemon-through-tcp-socker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add tcp option to sys config as shown here:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/docker

OPTIONS="--host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

After restarting docker, I could connect to remote docker server using python.

Comment: Please tell me you do not expose port 2375 to the world. If you run on Amazon, people can run bots to abuse your services, which can cost you thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're using docker-py.

Also, it sounds like maybe you're not familiar with TLS, so please read the documentation for [using TLS with docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tls/). You may need to download your TLS files and copy them local to the docker-py client as they are used to authenticate that you are authorized to connect to the Docker daemon.

I hope your remote Docker daemon is not exposed to the world.

If it is not running TLS (exposed to the world):

```
client = docker.Client(base_url='<https_url>', tls=False)
```

If it is secured with TLS (not exposed to the world):

```
client = docker.Client(base_url='<https_url>', tls=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not answer, but need your feedback.

The error message is: `Connection refused`, so can you run the command:

```
telnet 52.90.216.176  2375
```

To confirm if there is no firewall issue. Sometime the port is `2376`